# Ui-router modal injection error on minification

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-router, bootstrap-modal

I'm using ui-router and ui-bootstrap/modal

I've got a sale screen split in 2 so I have a left side with the cart and the right one can have the catalog, an edit product or a payment section.

I need to have a modal in all states  so I've created a function to add in some ui-router states.
Here's the function:

```
var modalSaleDelete = ['$state', '$modal',
    function($state, $modal) {
      $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'views/sale/delete.html',
        resolve: {
          parentScope: function($rootScope) {
            return $rootScope.parentScope;
          }
        },
        controller: function($scope, parentScope) {

          $scope.delete = function() {
            // TODO: change the way this is called
            parentScope.resetOrder();

            parentScope = null;
            $scope.$close('cancel');
          };

          $scope.cancel = function() {
            parentScope = null;
            $scope.$dismiss('cancel');
          };
        }
      }).result.then(function() {
        return $state.transitionTo($state.$current.parent);
      }, function() {
        return $state.transitionTo($state.$current.parent);
      });
    }
  ];
```

Then I put that in every state:

```
    .state('sale.new.catalog.delete', {
      url: '/delete',
      onEnter: modalSaleDelete
    })
```

It works great on development but when I minify this I get an error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.24/$injector/unpr?p0=aProvider%20%3C-%20a
    at http://localhost/ociWeb/code/dist/scripts/vendor.29d508bc.js:3:26944
    at http://localhost/ociWeb/code/dist/scripts/vendor.29d508bc.js:4:11462
    at Object.c [as get] (http://localhost/ociWeb/code/dist/scripts/vendor.29d508bc.js:4:10723)
    at http://localhost/ociWeb/code/dist/scripts/vendor.29d508bc.js:4:11557
    at c (http://localhost/ociWeb/code/dist/scripts/vendor.29d508bc.js:4:10723)
    at Object.d [as invoke] (http://localhost/ociWeb/code/dist/scripts/vendor.29d508bc.js:4:11008)
    at http://localhost/ociWeb/code/dist/scripts/vendor.29d508bc.js:8:20044
    at Object.f [as forEach] (http://localhost/ociWeb/code/dist/scripts/vendor.29d508bc.js:3:27387)
    at j (http://localhost/ociWeb/code/dist/scripts/vendor.29d508bc.js:8:19961)
    at Object.k.open (http://localhost/ociWeb/code/dist/scripts/vendor.29d508bc.js:8:20414)
```

I debugged that and aProvider should be '$state'.

Any idea on how to make that work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate EVERY injection for minification to work.  Or, if you are using an angular-aware minifier, it probably doesn't understand which functions are injected by UI-Router and which are standard functions.

```
var modalSaleDelete = ['$state', '$modal',
    function($state, $modal) {
      $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'views/sale/delete.html',
        resolve: {
          parentScope: [ '$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
            return $rootScope.parentScope;
          }]
        },
        controller: [ '$scope', 'parentScope', function($scope, parentScope) {

          $scope.delete = function() {
            // TODO: change the way this is called
            parentScope.resetOrder();

            parentScope = null;
            $scope.$close('cancel');
          };

          $scope.cancel = function() {
            parentScope = null;
            $scope.$dismiss('cancel');
          };
        }]
      }).result.then(function() {
        return $state.transitionTo($state.$current.parent);
      }, function() {
        return $state.transitionTo($state.$current.parent);
      });
    }
  ];
```

Comment: I'm actually using an angular-aware minifier and that's just as you said, I need to inject $state in the right point. The problem is finding it because the stack only shows vendor functions so I don't really know where to start debugging my part. Thanks for the help, though

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting them manually by creating an inject property. Do you have a jsfiddle or plunker set up?

```
  modalSaleDelete.$inject = ['$state', '$modal'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've figured it out. I don't see why but the problem was in resolve.
I solved it injecting '$state' in resolve though it's not needed.
When debugging I just saw the aProvider was trying to be injected in there.

```
var modalSaleDelete = ['$rootScope', '$state', '$modal',
    function($rootScope, $state, $modal) {
      $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'views/sale/delete.html',
        resolve: {
          parentScope: ['$state', '$rootScope', function($state, $rootScope) {
            return $rootScope.parentScope;
          }]
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$state', 'parentScope', function($scope, $state, parentScope) {

          $scope.delete = function() {
            // TODO: change the way this is called
            parentScope.resetOrder();

            parentScope = null;
            $scope.$close();
          };

          $scope.cancel = function() {
            parentScope = null;
            $scope.$dismiss();
          };
        }]
      }).result.then(function() {
        // close
        return $state.transitionTo($state.current.name.replace('.delete', ''));
      }, function() {
        // dismiss
        return $state.transitionTo($state.current.name.replace('.delete', ''));
      });
    }
  ];
```